# Proof of convergence of integral sequence using the definition of the limit

Tags: convergence-divergence, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

"Let f(x) be a continuous, positive and decreasing function. Use the definition of the limit
to prove that

> $$\int_{1}^{∞}f(x)dx$$ converges ⇔ the sequence $$a_{n}=\int_{1}^{n}f(x)dx$$ converges."

I'm struggling with this proof. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Use", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your first proof-heavy class.  One rule: always write down the definitions of the terms in your proof.  It will point you in the direction of exactly what it is you need to be proving.

$\int_1^\infty f(x) dx = \lim_\limits {n\to\infty} \int_1^n f(x) dx$

The integral converges if the limit exists.

Suppose: 
$\lim_\limits {n\to\infty} \int_1^n f(x) dx = L$

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N>0$ such that $n>N\implies |\int_1^n f(x) dx - L| < \epsilon$

If $n \in \mathbb N$:
$\int_1^n f(x) dx = a_n$

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N>0$ such that $n>N\implies |a_n - L| < \epsilon$

The sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $L$ if $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N>0$ such than $n>N \implies |a_n-L|< \epsilon$

If the integral converges, the sequence converges.

To prove it the other way:

If sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges it is Cauchy.

$n,m>N \implies |a_n-a_m|< \epsilon\\
|\int_m^n f(x) dx| < \epsilon$

$f(x)$ positive is continuous and monotonically decreasing.

$0\le\int_m^r f(x)dx \le \int_m^n f(x)dx<\epsilon$ if $m<r<n$

note $m, n$ are integers while $r$ is real.

$m>N, r>m \implies |\int_m^r f(x)dx| < \epsilon$

Comment: A suggestion to add in your first paragraph about proof-writing: If you never use the assumptions, *the proof is wrong*. This is one of those cases.

Comment: @T.Bongers  You are right, I had only proven one direction.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend starting by carefully writing out the definitions.

$$
\int_0^\infty f(t)dt := \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_0^x f(t)dt
$$
What does it mean for this limit to converge to, say, $a \in \mathbb{R}$. It means for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x \geq c$,  $|\int_0^x f(t)dt - a| < \epsilon \qquad (\ast)$

On the other hand, if $a_n := \int_0^n f(t)dt$, then the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converging to $a$ means for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t for all $m \geq k$, $|a_m-a|<\epsilon$, i.e $|\int_0^m f(t)dt - a| < \epsilon$  The problem is asking you to investigate the difference between these two definitions-- the forward direction is (hopefully) rather straightforward, (fix $\epsilon>0$, if the first limit converges, you get your $c \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $(\ast)$ holds for [all] $x \geq c$, can you see a candidate for the aforementioned $k$?)

The reverse direction is a little more tricky and will involve invoking the hypotheses on $f$ (i.e continuity and monotonicity). As a hint, try considering a function for which the proposition *doesn't* hold and investigate what's going wrong. I recommend getting a piece of paper and drawing the following function in the xy plane, first draw the points $(0,0), (\frac{1}{4},1), (\frac{1}{2},0), (\frac{3}{4},-1), (1,0)$, connect each point to the following by a straight line, you should now have two triangles of equal area, one below the x-axis, one above-- repeat this pattern for all $x \geq 0$. Now notice $\int_0^1 f(t)dt=0$ (the positive and negative areas are equal), in fact $\int_0^n f(t)dt=0$ for all $n$, and hence the sequence $\{a_n\}$ clearly converges. But does $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_0^x f(t)dt$ exist? Why not?

Good luck!